# Sending App Notification via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In their docs, Facebook indicates you can send notifications to users with an [App Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications)

I've converted my app to be of category game, have an app token, and try to send a notification to a user, but get this in response to API  `POST` `/v2.12/some-user-id/notifications`

```
{
  "error": {
     "message": "(#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications",
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 200,
     "fbtrace_id": "sometraceid"
  }
}
```

Is simply case where the documentation is outdated and notifications are no longer allowed or am I'm missing something?

Comment: What do you mean you coverted your app to be a game? Is your app actually a game or not?

Comment: Set the category of the app to be 'Game' in the app `Settings -> Basic`.  The App isn't anything yet, just exists to try out features available.  Wanted to see what was possible and learn about the Graph API.

Comment: Make sure it actually is a game. Otherwise the permission will never be approved by Facebook

Comment: Got it.  I'm not planning on trying to get approved, just wanted to experiment with the Graph API to see what's exposed and what's not for various permission sets and App settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like simply adding the category 'Game' to your app does not make it a Web Games Platform needed to send notifications (as noted in comments).   You need to add a `Platform` to your app of type Facebook Web Game.

[image]

Comment: _"Looks like simply adding the category 'Game' to your app does not make it a game"_ - of course it makes it a game. What it does not, is set up the Web Games Platform - which is a requirement to send App Notifications, because that is what users clicking on those notifications will be redirected to.